# ANR when using ksoap2 to send data to web services

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I am currently able of sending stuff into a server with ksoap2 library for android.
Now I have the need to make sure that this line doesn't block the app and makes it ANR:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(connection.getSOAP_ACTION(), envelope);
```

If by any reason i cant reach the server (for example the server is shutdown) this call blocks the app. how can i treat this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run calls like this within an `AsyncTask`, so it doesn't block the UI Thread.

Also, you might be interested in this [blog article on Painless threading in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Ok, currently i am doing this with a handler. Can't i do it like that?

Comment: Can you post more of your code, so we can see the handler implementation?

Comment: Ah ok so i can do it with handler and assign a thread to the part of code that makes the .call right?

Comment: Glad I could help so quickly.